# What Replaces Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn, fxcop, roslyn-code-analysis, visual-studio-2019

I'm toying with getting our team and projects ready for VS 2019.  Right away, trying to set up Code Analysis for a new project, I find this:

[image]

So, if this is deprecated (and apparently can't even be used, so I'm thinking "deprecated" really means "gone"), where are we supposed to set up our Rule Sets?  Is there some other location, or perhaps an altogether new solution to the problem of style and code quality?

Comment: This fat got chewed in [this github issue page](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/2434).

Comment: You need to install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers is deprecated)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Going forward, static analysis will be provided by Roslyn analyzers: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers

[Migrate from FxCop code analysis to .NET compiler platform analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/code-quality/fxcop-analyzers?view=vs-2019)

Comment: And here is a section on code analyzers in VS 2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/visualstudio/code-quality/fxcop-analyzers?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks, @MunchyYDL. I've added that link to the answer.

Comment: I suppose this means I need to dig in more.  I was previously under the impression that those Code Analysis rule sets WERE Roslyn analyzers.

Comment: There is a plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MicrosoftCodeAnalysis2019

Comment: > If you are already using the equivalent NuGet package (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FXCopAnalyzers), then installing this extension will cause issues (see issue here). Please install the latest NuGet package rather than the extension if this is the case.

Comment: You need to install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers is deprecated)

Answer (score -3):

Microsoft [IntelliCode](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/intellicode/) looks great!

Comment: IntelliCode is a coding assistance tool, not a code validation tool.