# How to install the VS2019 CodeAnalyis tools using vs_BuildTools.exe

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, visual-studio-2019, roslyn-code-analysis

We're upgrading our build agents from VS2017 to VS2019.  We use CodeAnalysis in our CI pipeline, so we install the CodeAnalysis workload using:

```
C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools
```

This creates a directory called `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\CodeAnalysis`

When I try this with VS2019, I don't get such a directory.  I've checked other possible locations by searching for `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets` as well.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019) seem to say it's in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VisualStudioExtensionBuildTools`, but that doesn't work either.  I've also tried `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.ArchitectureTools.Managed` and `Microsoft.Component.CodeAnalysis.SDK` but no luck.  Anyone know how to install this from the command line?

Comment: Are you looking for FxCop?  Maybe the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598152/what-replaces-code-analysis-in-visual-studio-2019?

Comment: Yea, I think some stuff has moved around in this version.  I'll have to figure out where the new stuff is and how to use it..  What's strange is when I install VS2019 Pro, I get that "CodeAnalysis" directory where I'd expect it, but it doesn't seem to get installed on our build machine using vs_buildtools.exe.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices
```

Comment: This worked for me, as well. Weird that there does not seem to be a matching UI option in the installer.

Comment: As a note for others like me, "vs_buildtools.exe" is the setup installer that is downloaded and will have those words in the exe but will also include a version number.

Comment: In the UI its called 'C# and Visual Basic' under 'Development activities'