# How to report out errors of Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2019 v16.9+

Tags: logging, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019, code-analysis, analyzer

Following [What Replaces Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598152/what-replaces-code-analysis-in-visual-studio-2019), I understand that `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` [is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/analyzers-faq?view=vs-2019#fxcop-analyzers-versus-.net-analyzers). Previously, the Code Analysis generated an automated XML file with all the warnings and errors in the template of `MyApplication.exe.CodeAnalysisLog.xml`.

[image: VS 2019: Right-click Project > Analyze and Code Cleanup > Run Code Analysis]

It seems like those new .NET Analyzers do not work the same way. **Is it possible to generate a report *(log)* with those errors using the new analyzer?** It would be nice if an XML file could be generated, although there is no requirement for the file format.

It is my goal to create a CI build for which I will be able to track these warnings/errors and fail the build itself.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also have need of this same thing.  I have been unable to find a way and it seems to ignore the CodeAnalysisLogFile value.